# copyright information for image repositories (schema.org, json-ld)

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, copyright-display

This is not exactly a technical question, it's about understanding the elements of CreativeWork and ImageObject in schema.org.

When creating structured data for an image, there are some attributes I can use to convey the copyright information, notably:

- creator
- copyrightHolder
- license

This looks quite straightforward for me (even considering the legal differences of "copyright" in the Anglo-American and European worlds).

What I'm looking for is how to include the copyright information from pictures bought on image repositories like iStock. The information provided looks like: `istock.com ©acreator ID-000000000`.

How is this information meant to be used with schema.org?

As *copyrightHolder* is meant to be a *Person* or *Organization*, using the string 'istock.com ©someone' as the person's or organisation's name doesn't seem to be the right thing to do.

So I came up with this JSON-LD code:

```
[
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "contentUrl": "https://path/to/my/image",
    "copyrightHolder": {
      "name": "istock.com"
    },
    "creator": {
      "name": "someone"
    },
    "copyrightNotice": "istock.com ©acreator ID-000000000",
    "license": "https://www.istockphoto.com/en/legal/license-agreement"
  }
]
```

I'm still not sure where to put the ID of the image, and also I'm not happy using the id on istock.com as "name" attribute for "creator".

I could also only use the copyrightNotice and not use "creator" and "copyrightHolder" but I'm not sure if I'd meet the legal requirement then.

Answer (score 0):

The schema.org information not really related to **any** legal requirement issues (It is vocabulary for search engines).

The credit should be visible to the user (With -or- Without schema) if the license requires adding a credit (Who is the copyrightHolder VS creator also not related to schema.org).

**More important:**

> Don't mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page. [Google Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/sd-policies)

So only add structured data that visible to the users. I guess you don't have in your web design clickable text to **istock** license (So you don't need to add this).

Even [creditText](https://schema.org/creditText) could be enough.

**Example (The markup visible to readers):**
[image]

##### Basic example - Withtout

```
<img src="italy-beach.jpg" alt="italy beach."/>

By Jane Doe
copyrights istock.com. Author Leonardo
```

##### Basic example - With

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <img src="italy-beach.jpg"
  alt="italy beach."
  itemprop="contentUrl" />
  By <span itemprop="author">Jane Doe</span>
  copyrights <span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization" itemprop="copyrightHolder"><span itemprop="name">istock.com</span> Author: <span>Leonardo</span>
</div>
```

[image]

---

##### image id

You can use https://schema.org/identifier.